# RDLC - Repeat header rows in Word document

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a tablix with lots of rows. Now I want to export the report to word. On each page of the word document, the header should be repeated.

I tried the properties section of the tablix and I also used the advanced mode to set the row property "RepeatOnNewPage". 
But in word there is no difference.

Any ideas???

Comment: Does it work when you display it in the report viewer?

Comment: No, it is also wrong

Comment: I found I have better luck with using "group header" rows for header and setting repeat properties in group properties instead if using tablix header.